# Включить зависимости(jar файл) Maven в java код, в среде NetBeans

Tags: java, maven

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно импортировать в класс Person  классы DateTime и Instance библиотеки Joda-Times. Но я не знаю как. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Зачем использовать NetBeans, если есть бесплатный Eclipse? или хотя бы Idea(бесплатна для студентов)

Comment: зачем вам йода тайм. используйте классы LocalDate для даты и LocalDateTime для даты со временем, которые доступны с 8 версии джавы и входят в джава кор (по сути это и есть йода тайм, который в 8 версии вошел в джава кор)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было импортировать не весь архив с библиотекой, а только один  jar  файл- joda-time-2.10.4.jar